# Ангуляр 2 подгрузка всех модулей

Tags: angular2, импорт

Добрый вечер. А подскажите, может кто сталкивался... Есть архитекрура с разбиением по модулям. Как сделать так, чтобы при импорте не нужно было писать полный путь до модуля? Запаковываю через systemjs, компилирую через npm tsc. Хотелось бы найти решения именно с systemjs. Help плз)